# Hello world won't compile with "The value or constructor is not defined"

Tags: f#

```
let prefix prefixString baseString = 
    prefixString + " " + baseString

prefix "Hello" "World"
```

With the code above I'm getting the error `Stuff.fs(34,1): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'prefix' is not defined.`

I'm not entirely sure why this is happening, as I'm watching a [video series](https://youtu.be/Teak30_pXHk?t=807) on F# in which literally the same code is being compiled and ran successfully. Is there something wrong with my environment?

Comment: Where/how do you try to run your code? The code looks perfectly valid, and runs as expected using `fsharpi` on macOS Sierra. Also, how does the remainder if the file look? The error is reported on line 34, so something is missing here.

Comment: That's what I don't understand, that snippet is the whole file. I try run it with Ionide's "run selection" from within VS Code.

Comment: Okay, I just tried to install the Ionide extension and every thing seems to work fine. Try use 'send file' instead of just send selection, if this works then you probably have forgotten to send the definition to the interpreter but only the usage of prefix which will cause the error you see.

Comment: I restarted VS Code multiple times and it just appeared to *start working*, without me reinstalling anything. I think it might have been a bug in Ionide, but at least now I'm able to run it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the comment, you mentioned that you are running the snippet using "run selection" command. This command runs the selected piece of code in F# Interactive which initially contains no definitions. So, if you select and run just the last line, you will get:

```
> prefix "Hello" "World";;
stdin(1,1): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'prefix' is not defined
```

This is because F# Interactive does not know what the definition of `prefix` is - it does not look for it automatically in your file. You can fix this by selecting everything and running all code in a single interaction, or you can first run the definition and then the last line, i.e.:

```
> let prefix prefixString baseString = 
    prefixString + " " + baseString;;
val prefix : prefixString:string -> baseString:string -> string

> prefix "Hello" "World";;
val it : string = "Hello World"
```

Note that when you run the first command, F# Interactive will print the type of the defined functions, so you can see what has just been defined.

The fact that F# Interactive has its own separate "state of the world" is quite important, as it also means that you need to re-run functions after you change them so that subsequent commands use the new definition.